# Magento/PHP: Add static block to end of products list(Grid) on category page?

Tags: php, magento, iterator

I am basing my code off a similar solution which displays the block every 3 products:

```
<?php if($i % 3 == 0){ ?>
-- static block here --        
<?php } ?>
```

I would like to display the static block once after all products vs multiple times, every 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to render your static block at the bottom of the product list, then go to your list.phtml page and scroll to the bottom. Prior to the bottom , call your static block like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

That should do the trick, and it will be outside of the if/else statement for list/grid so it will render regardless of which view mode you're in.

Comment: Thankyou, but I need this to be at the end of the product list, but it needs to be a list item and appear like a normal product, not outside the <ul>.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a static block named "mystaticblock". The code below will work.

```
<?php 
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('mystaticblock')->toHtml();
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I am looking to only display the product at the end of all products vs every 3.